# Unable to locate element error while trying to locate an input box element using Selenium through Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I´m trying to find a text box with Python and Selenium.. I Tried by_css_selector, bY XPATH, by ID, by name but the message is always the same:

`Unable to locate element: #x-auto-225-input`

this is the piece of html. I Want to find the textbox to fill it.

```
<td class="x-table-layout-cell" role="presentation" style="padding: 2px;">
    <div role="presentation" class=" x-form-field-wrap  x-component" id="x-auto-225" style="width: 150px;"></div>
    <input type="text" class=" x-form-field x-form-text " id="x-auto-225-input" name="PURCHASE_ORDER_CODE_NAME" tabindex="0" style="width: 150px;">
</td>
```

My last attempt was:

```
pc = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#x-auto-225-input").click()
pc.send_keys("7555425-1")
```

Comment: can you please provide the html of your page

Comment: have you tried `find_element_by_name("PURCHASE_ORDER_CODE_NAME")`

Comment: if possible can provide the link of your web page?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Use the Expected condition and wait for the element to be visible before performing the operation. I don't see any issue with the locator or the code.

Comment: Is this element in an IFRAME? Have you tried a wait?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the html, `id` mentioned can be dynamic, so you can't put the static id in your identifier.
However, as `name` attribute is present in the html, you can use that to identify your element, like:

```
browser.find_element_by_name("PURCHASE_ORDER_CODE_NAME").click()
```

**Updated answer as per discussion with the OP**

As an iframe is present on the UI, you need to first switch to the iframe and then click on the element.
To switch to `iframe` you can use:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))
```

and then use:

```
pc = browser.find_element_by_name("PURCHASE_ORDER_CODE_NAME")
pc.click()
pc.send_keys("7555425-1")
```

if you want to switch back to the default content, you can use:

```
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: I´ve tried :Unable to locate element: [name="PURCHASE_ORDER_CODE_NAME"]

Comment: @wmoura12 can you check that is there any iframe available in the html ?

Comment: yes. <iframe id="x-auto-510" name="gxt.formpanel-5" style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

Comment: @wmoura12 i have updated my answer, please check the updated answer.

Comment: @wmoura12 let me know if the updated answer works for you

Comment: Tks a lot. IT Works, but the send_keys failed.browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_name("gwtIndex"))
pc = browser.find_element_by_name("PURCHASE_ORDER_CODE_NAME").click()
pc.send_keys("7555425-1") - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Comment: @wmoura12 have updated my answer. Please check now and let me know if it works

Comment: Your first code block has `pc = ....click()`. `.click()` returns `void` so nothing is going to get assigned into `pc` and it will likely throw an error. You've got it right in the third block, just update the first block to remove the `pc =` to avoid the problem.

Comment: @JeffC yeah actually i updated the answer after discussion with the OP, just missed to update the first block. Thanks for mentioning it !!

Comment: @wmoura12 Take a look at his third block of code again and sync your code up to match. I think you are using an outdated version of the code. See my comment up two for why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to invoke `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.x-form-field.x-form-text[id$='-input'][name='PURCHASE_ORDER_CODE_NAME']"))).click();
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class=' x-form-field x-form-text ' and contains(@id,'-input')][@name='PURCHASE_ORDER_CODE_NAME']"))).click();
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Tks for your response. This code returned Timeout. TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _expected-conditions_. Debug your code through `find_element_by_*` in-conjunction with `time.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try another "selector" approach. Ex(Javascript):

```
selenium.By.xpath('//*[@data-icon="edit"]')
driver.findElement(by).click()
```